# Which text field should I use in word and how to fill it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use a text field in my word template document but I confused which one should I use?!!
which one you recommend?

1. Rick text
2. Text
3. Text Form Field

My second question is how to address these component in Macro? I use below code:
ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextboxName")

Third question is how to **set a value to this component in Macro**? so many website use .Value but I don't know why I cannot find this field in above component.

Last question is: if I use any form field, **a gray shadow exist below my component, how I can remove it?** it is even coming in check print.:(

[image]

I am using word 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You would add : textFormField.
2. you would pass value by **Me.FormFields("Text1").Result = "abc"**
3. in your controls tab,
   somewhere next to the formField control find the "**formFieldShadding**"
   control. when you select that control your gray shadding will
   disappear.

Comment: May I know how I can add a row in table also with Macro?